# How can I call some function without using onPress which is received as prop

Tags: react-native, function, onpress

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.clearButton} onPress={clear}>
```

I want to use use the `clear`(it is a function which clears a selectedItem from picker field) function assigned to  onPress independently . 
For Example in some if condition as follow:

```
if(someCondition){
  // I want to use clear function here.
}
```

Please tell me how can I do it. Below is complete function.

```
function renderField (settings) {
    const { getLabel, clear } = settings
     
     if(someCondition){
         // I want to use clear function here.
     }
    return (
            <View>
              
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={clear}>
                <Text>Clear</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              
               <Text>{getLabel(selectedItem)}</Text>
            
            </View>
           )
 }
```

Whole Code::

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { Alert, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import { CustomPicker } from 'react-native-custom-picker'

export default function Test() {
    const options = [
      {
        color: '#2660A4',
        label: 'One',
        value: 1
      },
      {
        color: '#FF6B35',
        label: 'Two',
        value: 2
      },
    ]
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
            <CustomPicker
                placeholder={'Please select your favorite item...'}
                options={options}
                getLabel={item => item.label}
                fieldTemplate={renderField}
                optionTemplate={renderOption}
                onValueChange={value => {
                    Alert.alert('Selected Item', value ? JSON.stringify(value) : 'No item were selected!')
                }}
            />
      </View>
    )

    function renderField (settings) {
    const { selectedItem, defaultText, getLabel, clear } = settings
    
    /* React.useEffect(() => {
        if (selectedItem) {
          return
        }
      
        clear()
      }, [selectedItem, clear]) */

    return (
        
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View>
          {!selectedItem && <Text style={[styles.text, { color: 'red' }]}>{defaultText}</Text>}
          {selectedItem && (
            <View style={styles.innerContainer}>
              <TouchableOpacity style={styles.clearButton} onPress={clear}>
                <Text style={{ color: '#fff' }}>Clear</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <Text style={[styles.text, { color: selectedItem.color }]}>
                {getLabel(selectedItem)}
              </Text>
            </View>
          )}
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }

  function renderOption(settings) {
    const { item, getLabel } = settings
    return (
      <View style={styles.optionContainer}>
        <View style={styles.innerContainer}>
          <View style={[styles.box, { backgroundColor: item.color }]} />
          <Text style={{ color: item.color, alignSelf: 'flex-start' }}>{getLabel(item)}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

::[reference](https://github.com/budiadiono/react-native-custom-picker#readme)::

**My Goal : ** I want to change the selected value to default based on some condition as I'm implementing two custom pickers, So when value in 1st picker changes, I want to set the value of 2nd picker to default.

Answer (score 0):

You want to run a side effect,

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  if (!someCondition) {
    return
  }

  clear()
}, [someCondition, clear])
```

Comment: Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.